# Usar cin.putback cuando cin esta leyendo de un istringstream

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string fdsa = "hola";
    
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::cin.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf());
    
    std::cin.putback(';');
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fdsa.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cin.putback(fdsa[i]);
    }

    char car;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> car;
        std::cout << car;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

De salida no me da "nada".
Mientras que lo que esperaba era algo del estilo:

`aloh;`

Ya que en la documentación de putback dice:

"Puts the character ch back to the input stream so the next extracted character will be ch. "

Hasta ahora el `std::cin.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf());` lo estuve interpretando cómo que cin en vez de leer de la entrada estándar se pone a leer de iss. Por eso me parecía razonable esperar que putback funcione. Pero pensandolo un poco más no me suena que leer el búfer de un flujo sea lo mismo que leer del flujo en sí, ¿cierto?

En caso de que venga por ahí la mano, ¿como podría hacer que cin realmente este respaldado por iss?

¿se entendió la pregunta?

EDIT 1:

La razón por la cual estoy preguntando esto no es porque quiero dar vuelta una cadena. Lo estoy preguntando porque para cierto otro programa que estoy haciendo me viene bien poder meter cualquier carácter en un istringstream.

Answer (score 1):

La [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback) dice:

> First clears eofbit, then behaves as UnformattedInputFunction. After
> constructing and checking the sentry object, if rdbuf() is not null,
> calls rdbuf()->sputbackc(ch), **which calls rdbuf()->pbackfail(ch) if ch
> does not equal the most recently extracted character**.

Es decir, no deberías poner caracteres arbitrarios con `putback`, solo el último caracter que recibiste con `get`.

El propósito de todo `istream` es realizar operaciones de lectura con `istream`. No tiene por qué soportar escritura. Entonces, por qué usarlo de otro modo?

Si te interesa leer y escribir, usa un [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). Por ejemplo:

```
std::stringstream ss("Hola mundo");
ss.seekg(0);
ss << "Chau";
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
// Imprime: Chau mundo
```

Comment: Esto no lo aclare en la pregunta, pero lo que quiero hacer **no** es dar vuelta una cadena. Quiero poder meter cualquier carácter en un stream. Ahora edito la pregunta.

Por cierto me quede pensando porque es que sí en mi código de ejemplo saco las líneas que dicen "std::istringstream iss;  std::cin.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf());" funciona bien?
Definitivamente por la documentación que me estás mostrando no debería.